# Can you use JavaScript or text formulas in Apple iWork Numbers?

Tags: iwork-numbers

Is there a way to use JavaScript in [Apple iWork Numbers](https://www.apple.com/iwork/)?

I'm having trouble adding a Round function around my existing function and it's showing errors.

[image]

[image]

It says it contains an error but doesn't say what it is. I'd like to use JavaScript or something like that it if possible.

After that I converted it to text and here is what it says:

[image]

This looks correct to me. If I could enter this and use it as a formula I would do that. But as text it does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I have to Show formula as Text. After selecting that option I can type in text.

[image]